# How do I change an URL ID to a more secure (unguessable) number?

Tags: php

Just trying to do some security on my website and trying to figure out the best route to secure an ID into another number.

EXAMPLE: http://localhost/page.php?id=190 TO: http://localhost/page.php?id=2234923498734

Comment: What are your requirements? Can you store the “secure ID” in a database? How long should it be? What exactly are you trying to defend against?

Comment: In the end, how did you do this? I too am looking for something similar. Can you tell how you achieved this. I posted a similar query and then came across this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using md5($id), then store the md5 of the ID in the database and look up the record based on that.

Comment: Trivial to break with a rainbow table. At minimum there should be some salting.

Comment: and the problem of md5 is that you do not have an int, harder to secure (a simple int cast isn't available anymore)

Comment: @regilero: converting to an int is easy by simply cutting off the right number of bytes.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann : you're right, I always forget this is hex number, so it's a number. But reducing it will make it less unique, which is a problem for a hash.

Comment: @regilero: If reducing it to the maximum number of bits possible for an int, it is the optimum which is doable for a hash to avoid collisions.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a hash-function like md5(). (With salting of course)
Or you could think of any injective math-function you like to make your real id harder to guess..

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the **[base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)** function if you need an easy way to hide the id from users (**[base64_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)** is the opposite function used to decode base64 encoded stuff).

Do note that base64 encoding doesn't make your data more secure just obfuscated enough for your visitors not to be able to read the id immediatelly.

Comment: base64 would be very easy to decrypt because of the look of base64, and there is actually no need to decrypt it, he just needs a hash function

Answer (score 0):

A simple **bitwise XOR** with a **salt** you give you fast and easy results (here the salt is 123456789):

```
php > echo (190 ^ 123456789);
123456939
php > echo (191 ^ 123456789);
123456938
php > echo (192 ^ 123456789);
123456981
php > echo (193 ^ 123456789);
123456980
php > echo (194 ^ 123456789);
123456983
```

with the nice fact that the XOR is a bijection:

```
123456983 ^ 123456789 = 194
```

So reusing the same salt on the given id will gives you the real id. But as said by @mightyuhu the problem is now math, you should maybe add the 'math' tag to get some more complex bijections.